# gradle, local project as dependency/base for another

Tags: android, gradle, libgdx, build.gradle

I have 2 projects both based on Libgdx. I would actually like to use 1 project (BaseProject) as a base for the other (MainProject), and I would like to remove the libgdx dependency all together from the MainProject, so instead of;

```
MainProject > libgdx
BaseProject > libgdx
```

I will have

```
MainProject > BaseProject > libgdx
```

The current file tree is like this;

```
/root
---/BaseProject
------/settings.gradle
------/build.gradle
------/base-core
---------/build.gradle
------/base-android
---------/build.gradle
---/MainProject
------/settings.gradle
------/build.gradle
------/core
---------/build.gradle
------/android
---------/build.gradle
```

The same applies for modules (BaseProject) base-desktop, base-html, base-ios, and (MainProject) desktop, html, ios.

The reason I want to do this is because I have modified a fair amount of the libgdx backends in the BaseProject, and added a lot of my own tools, which I would like to use in several projects.

So far I have tried;

```
MainProject/settings.gradle

include 'base', 'core', 'desktop', 'android', 'html'
project(':base').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../BaseProject')


MainProject/build.gradle

apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    implementation project(':base')
}
```

This throws an error;

> ERROR: Project with path ':base-desktop' could not be found in project
>   ':base'.

I'm at a loss of how to set this up. Ideally, I can access libgdx through the BaseProject dependency, and my application launchers will extend my BaseProject launchers rather than libgdx's.